# Get channel list in Slack

Tags: node.js, integration, slack-api, slack

I'm  using Incoming webhooks to send message to the channel. I decide the channel in JSON format.

```
var message = {
    "text" : "text",
    "channel" : "#general",
    "username" : "me"
};
```

How can I get the list of channels in Slack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [the Web API](https://api.slack.com/web). Incoming webhooks are insufficient for this.

(Specifically, you want [channels.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list).)

Comment: I see. Should i authenticate while using the Web api?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Yes, authentication is required to use the API.